# What is an "almost tight bound"

Tags: lower-bounds, upper-bound

I am doing some research for a paper that I am writing and one of the papers that I have come across that has some interesting results talks about an "almost tight bound". I am not a computer scientist and I feel like I understand the actual math of the bounding. However, I don't know what it means by "almost tight". Is this a common thing in CS?

Comment: It means that there is a lower bound, and there is an upper bound, and the gap between them is "small". What exactly "small" means, depends on the context.

Comment: @Dmitry You should post an answer instead of a comment so that it can be accepted.